# Group concat for Scala sequence of case objects

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm wondering if there is elegant way to do group concat by pure scala for the seq of scala case object.  Here is the way I did it.

```
case class UserToAccounts
(
  id: Int,
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  accountId: Seq[Int]
)

case class User
(
  id: Int,
  email: String,
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  accountId: Int
)

val users = Seq(
  User(1, "foo@test.com", "test", "foo", 1),
  User(1, "foo@test.com", "test", "foo", 2),
  User(2, "bar@test.com", "test", "bar", 1)
)

val groupedUsers = users
      .groupBy(u => (u.id, u.email, u.firstName, u.lastName))
      .mapValues( x => x.map( y => y.accountId))
      .map(z => UserToAccounts(
      id = z._1._1,
      email = z._1._2,
      firstName = z._1._3,
      lastName = z._1._4,
      accountIds = z._2
    ))

println(groupedUsers)

List(UserToAccounts(2,bar@test.com,test,bar,List(1)), UserToAccounts(1,foo@test.com,test,foo,List(1, 2)))
```

Thank u in advance for the good advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to group by the `id` of the `User` class which will get you a map from `User.id` to `List[User]`.  You can then map over that and use it to directly create your `UserToAccounts` object.  You will need to `map` over the `userList` to extract out all the account ids for that user:

```
users.groupBy(_.id).map {
  case (userId, userList) =>
    val user = userList.head
    UserToAccounts(userId,
                   user.email,
                   user.firstName,
                   user.lastName,
                   userList.map(_.accountId))
}
```